# Cannot play a rtsp video stream which dont have a audio channel

Tags: video, streaming, rtsp, playback

I used VLC player to stream my rtsp stream. Using VLC i can be able to stream that, but using some other player(Lead Tools player) i am unable to play that stream. Anyway in my stream I do not have a audio channel. So what would caused to make that unplayable.
I used wireshark to analyse data packets receiving and found it will break at DESCRIBE command.Latter part after DESCRIBE command including SETUP command is missing.